# Replacing Tile in the Kitchen without the removal of the cabinet

Tags: flooring, kitchens, tile

I want to replace the tile in my kitchen

but the Cabinet that has the stove, dishwasher and sink is on top of the tile.

Is there a way I can replace the tile with hardwood without the removal or disassemble of the cabinet?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Treat the cabinet the same as a wall.  If vinyl tile can just lay the hardwood on top in some cases.  Ceramic tile will probably make the floor too high.

Comment: @crip659 do you mean to lay vinyl flooring on top of the tile? hmmm will it work?

Comment: It could work, it most likely will take some prep, a picture would help that includes where the tile stops at, and the surface of the tile.

Comment: @jack i added some photos

Comment: I should have detailed my question better. What I meant by where it stops at is where the tile meets different flooring, like a door and such. Mainly because that is where height of the floor changes.

Comment: Yes the vinyl floor can go over that, but the prep would be filling the areas where the joints are so the surface is flat. My opinion only, but nice floor, shame to cover it.

Comment: I was thinking of laying the new floor on top of the thin type vinyl tile.  Real ceramic tile is thicker so the extra rise might be too much at the other floors, but is up to you if the step/difference is worth it.  Type of new flooring is important, floating/glue down will be different from nailed down.  Nails and ceramic tile do not play nice together.

Comment: Do we assume the proscription against removing the cabinets is because the OP doesn't want to deal with removing the countertops?

Comment: @Huesmann not sure how to remove the countertop, and the idea of laying the new floor vinyl on top of the ceramic is appealing especially since it will add another insolation from the basement and i do not need to worry about removing the old tile and wood in the other rooms. ( i am thinking of using vinyl all over the house floors)

Comment: @asmgx vinyl (LVT?) will be easier than hardwood.

Answer (score 1):

Hardwood? If you mean nailed down then the tile needs to come up. It  maybe should come up anyway if you have height issues where it transitions. Use a Toe-Kick Saw. The one pictured (Harbor Freight) has a wood blade but in checking the reviews a diamond blade (get a dry cut blade) will work with minor modifications. Will not get all the way into the corners so a chisel will be needed to clean up the corners. I would also protect your cabinets so they don't get scratched.[image: Saw1]

[image: Saw2]

Comment: What are you intending to be sawn with that—the tile?

Comment: yes, with a diamond blade